# Docker上のRailsアプリからEC2内のMySQLに接続できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, docker, amazon-ec2

`docker run project_name rails db:create` を実行すると以下のエラーが出ています．

```
Host 'ip-172-17-0-2.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
    Couldn't create 'development' database. Please check your configuration.
    rails aborted!
```

**状況**
同じEC2内に以下の2つが入っています．

1. Dockerで起動したRailsアプリ
2. MySQL

1は`docker run`で起動することはできているんですが．MySQLとの接続ができてないためエラーを吐いています．

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エラー

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

2は`mysqladmin ping -u root -p`で起動していることを確認してますし，localのsequel proから接続できることが確認できています．

database.ymlの設定ができていないのだと思うのですが，分かりません．
以下にdatabase.ymlのdefaultの部分を載せておきます．よろしくお願いします．

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  username: root
  password: password
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  pool: 5
```

Comment: 完全回答でないのでコメントで失礼します。とりあえず docker コンテナからみて仮想ネットワーク上にあるホストサーバーは localhost ではなく別マシンなので host パラメータが必要です。amazon Linux 上で docker を立てたことがないのでアドレスは不明ですが MAC なら docker_for_mac_internal みたいなホスト名でホストにアクセスできるのでアドレスを調べて database.yml に host: <アドレス> を追加すればアクセスできると思います

Comment: ありがとうございます．
hostにmysqlが動いているec2のprivate ipをセットしました．
しかし，うごかなかったです泣
アクセス拒否のエラーを調べた時に，
https://qiita.com/n0bisuke/items/bd86dd3a79cd7cbcd92e
こちらを参考にしてセットしたりしたのですが，，，